# How to rewrite xml file in Java

Tags: java, xml, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite a small part of a XML file.

The idea is, I can deal with the situation like following:

```
<Line>
     <P Name="Src">5</P>
     <P Name="Dst">4</P>
</Line>
```

However, sometimes, the XML file contains some information like this:

```
<Line>
    <P Name="Src">2</P>
    <P Name="Points">[3, 0]</P>
    <Branch>
      <P Name="Points">[0, 8]</P>
      <P Name="Dst">5</P>
    </Branch>
    <Branch>
      <P Name="Dst">3</P>
    </Branch>
</Line>
```

What I want is simple, I want to rewrite the right above information into the beggining pattern:

1). Delete the `<P Name="Points">[*,*]</P>`

2). Place the `<P Name="Src">*</P>` into each `<Branch>`

3). Change `<Branch>` into `<Line>`

The expected result will be :

```
<Line>
     <P Name="Src">2</P>
     <P Name="Dst">5</P>
</Line>
<Line>
     <P Name="Src">2</P>
     <P Name="Dst">3</P>
</Line>
```

Is there any recommendation or suggestion to do this

Thanks

Comment: I suggest reading up on SAX.  It's the obvious tool for this problem.

Comment: Xslt is great for this kind of transformations.

Comment: @DavidWallace Is SAX different from DOM to this?

Comment: @MGorgon is xslt availble for xml to xml transform?

Comment: Of course, xslt stands for "XML Transformations". It is made for it.

Comment: @MGorgon ok, I will read the doc. By the way, another question, the example I gave above is only part of my XML file. Can I use xslt only for part of the XML file, and the rest of xml stay the same?

Comment: Yes, same thing for SAX. You define what is to change. Good luck!

Comment: I hate to sound discouraging, but I would find this difficult in XSLT, if I were a beginner in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an XSLT that does the job. You might have to adjust the condition(s) on when to include or exclude a `<P>` element, here it just excludes `<P>` elements that has a `[` character in its text node.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <!-- By default, copy everything -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Special processing for Line elements that has one or more Branch children -->
    <xsl:template match="Line[count(Branch) > 0]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Branch" />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Special processing for Branch elements -->
    <xsl:template match="Branch">
        <Line>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="../P[not(contains(., '['))]" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="P[not(contains(., '['))]" />
        </Line>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note also that this XSL assumes that a `<Branch>`element cannot appear anywhere else than as a direct child of a `<Line>`element.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will give you feedback later.